Image orientation for .heic format is reset
I have to receive an image via form-data http request and send it to file storage.
However, a problem arises in the process - if the image is in .heic format (for example, iPhones are shot in this format) and it is vertical (height > width), then the image is converted to horizontal, that is, it simply lies on its side. I haven't noticed this problem on other formats.
I read about the lib github.com/rwcarlsen/goexif/exif, which allows you to get exif data, which also stores the orientation of the image.
Here is the function for getting a file from form-data of the fiber framework:
func ParseFileToBytes(c *fiber.Ctx, fileName string) ([]byte, error) {
    if c.Method() != fiber.MethodPatch {
        return nil, errlst.HttpErrInvalidRequest
    }

    formFile, err := c.FormFile(fileName)
    if err != nil { ... }

    file, err := formFile.Open()
    if err != nil { ... }
    defer file.Close()

    fileData, err := io.ReadAll(file)
    if err != nil { ... }

    exifData, err := exif.Decode(bytes.NewReader(fileData))
    if exifData == nil {
        logger.Log.Info("exifData is nil")
    } else {
        logger.Log.Info("exifData is not nil")
    }

    return fileData, nil
}

But “exifData is nil” is always displayed, so I can’t determine in any way what orientation the file was originally in order to adjust its further storage.
I will be glad for any help!

This lib helped me: https://github.com/evanoberholster/imagemeta
func rotateImage(imageData []byte, img image.Image) image.Image {
    exifData, err := imagemeta.Decode(bytes.NewReader(imageData))
    if err != nil {
        logger.Log.Error("EXIF data is not available for this image", zap.Error(err))
    } else {
        orientation := exifData.Orientation.String()
        logger.Log.Info("Image orientation is " + orientation)

        if orientation == "Rotate 90 CW" {
            img = imaging.Rotate270(img)
        }
    }
    return img
}

